# unable to convert blocks of objc to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, quickblox

While converting this code to swift I get error and I am unable to do so.
please help me converting this piece of objc code to swift.

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    // session created

    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.password = @"azhhdsf";
    user.login = @"dsfgsgf";

    // Registration/sign up of User
    [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        // Sign up was successful
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // Handle error here
        NSLog(@"error while signing up with QB");
    }];
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // handle errors
    NSLog(@"%@", response.error);
}];
```

In swift what I did is:

```
QBRequest.createSessionWithSuccessBlock({response: QBResponse!,session: QBASession! in
            let user = QBUUser()
            user.ID = 125345
            user.password = "kjjhfdsf"

            QBRequest.signUp(user, successBlock: nil, errorBlock: nil)
            }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in
                println("error")
        })
```

sorry for that silly question but I am not able to perform it.

Comment: What the error that you are getting

Comment: expected expression on QBResonse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
QBRequest.createSessionWithSuccessBlock({ (response: QBResponse, session: QBASession) in
    let user = QBUUser()
    user.password = "azhhdsf"
    user.login = "dsfgsgf"
    QBRequest.signUp(user, successBlock: {(response: QBResponse, user: QBUUser) in
            // Sign up was successful
        }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse) in
            // Handle error here
            NSLog("error while signing up with QB")
    })}, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse) in
        // handle errors
        NSLog("%@", response.error)
    }
)
```